# Autoincrement field support in dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a requirement of having auto increment field in the dynamoDB database. I could handle this by writing my own algorithmes but i just need to know if DynamoDB or AWS provides such a solution so that i can leverage that . Does anybody have any idea on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB doesn't provide this feature. An auto-increment key is usually just used as an easy way to get a unique ID for each record in your database table. There are other ways to generate unique IDs, such as UUID, that don't require you to know about the values previously stored in the table. I recommend you evaluate your use case to determine if UUIDs would solve your problem.

If you absolutely need an incrementing numeric key in your DynamoDB table, then one way to accomplish that would be to have a separate table that stores your last auto-increment value, and use DynamoDB Atomic Counters to increment that value whenever you need a key value for a new record. Of course this would mean that you now have to perform an update in one table plus an insert in another table every time you have a new record, so it's not an ideal scenario.

Comment: +1 - not too mention that the last identifier value becomes a bottle neck essentially reducing your theoretical max throughput for writes to 1000 IOPS - definitely not a scalable solution for anything but trivial loads

Comment: Thanks Mark ,   I absolutely need this auto increment field and since dynamoDB does not have this built in feature , i would need to go for some kind of idea you have recommended. 

By the way , this atomic counters , should we manage the thread synchronization here by our self  ? or Does the dynamo db atomic counter is thread safe ? What will happen if multiple threads reads this atomic counter at the same time

Comment: @JavaProgrammer DynamoDB Atomic Counters are thread safe. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters